# Is there a way to invalidate (update) screen from a thread without using a runnable

Tags: android, multithreading, android-view

I have a background thread that sleeps for 1/10 of a second, then re loops.  I would like it to invalidate the screen, so it will redraw and do a simple animation.  It seems like the only way I can invalidate the screen is if I do it in a Runnable, which  assume has a lot of overhead.

Is there a way to invalidate the screen inside a thread without using a runnable??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Android SDK has a built-in API for this purpose - [View.postInvalidate()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#postInvalidate%28%29):

> **public void postInvalidate ()**
>
> Cause an invalidate to happen on a subsequent cycle through the event loop. Use this to invalidate the View from a non-UI thread.
>
> This method can be invoked from outside of the UI thread only when this View is attached to a window.
>
> See Also
>
> ```
>  invalidate()  
>  postInvalidateDelayed(long)
> ```

Answer (score 0):

It's not legal to invoke any of the UI-related APIs from a background thread.  So you will need to use a `Runnable`.

If the only thing the background thread does is sleep, you can probably achieve the same effect without using a thread, by using the `CountDownTimer` class instead.  Or you can use the `Handler.postAtTime()` API to schedule a `Runnable` to run on your UI thread at a certain number of milliseconds in the future (again, without using a separate thread).

Answer (score 0):

I actually think the overhead is neglibable. But you could use an `AsyncTask` as follows:

```
new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {
  /* (non-Javadoc)
   * @see android.os.AsyncTask#doInBackground(Params[])
   */
  @Override
  protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
    while(true) { //probably want some other challenge here
      Thread.sleep(1000 / 10);
      publishProgress();
    }
    return null;
  }

  /* (non-Javadoc)
   * @see android.os.AsyncTask#onProgressUpdate(Progress[])
   */
  @Override
  protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
    super.onProgressUpdate(values);
    mMyView.invalidate();
  }
}.execute();
```

This is good as onProgressUpdate automatically runs on the UIThread so you dont have to create a new runnable everytime...

Answer (score 0):

Try to send a message to handler in your thread and invalidate in handleMessage.It might work.
Or use AsyncTask like Salil Pandit said.I think Async is better.